# Calculate the price at time t=0

Tags: black-scholes, finance, call

Assume the risk-free bond Bt and the stock St follow the dynamics of the Black & Scholes model
(with interest rate r, stock drift $\mu$ and volatility $\sigma$).

Calculate the price at time $t = 0$ of a derivative with maturity T and payoff $(S^3_t-K)^+$. I know I need to use the Black Scholes formula for price of a call to find the price of the derivative but the formula also contains $N(d_1)$ and $N(d_2)$ so how would this get affected?

Comment: I don't get the question. Which process is defined by $e^{\beta t}S_t^3$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand the question but I can try. I think the problem is to find the price of a contingent claim that has payoff $(S_T^3 - K)^+$. The well-known pricing formula is:
\begin{equation}
\pi(t)=\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[e^{-r(T-t)}(S_T^3 - K)^+|\mathcal{F}_t]
\end{equation}
Now put $Y=S^3$, by using Ito's Lemma
\begin{equation}
dY(t)=dS^3(t)=3S^2(t)dS(t) + \frac126S(t)\sigma^2S^2(t)dt
\end{equation}
In Black-Scholes model
\begin{equation}
dS(t)=\mu S(t) dt + \sigma S(t) dW(t)
\end{equation}
So we have:
\begin{equation}
dY(t)=3\mu S^3dt + 3\sigma^2S^3dt + 3\sigma S^3dW=(3\mu + 3\sigma^2)Ydt + 3\sigma YdW
\end{equation}
Now we define 
\begin{align}
\tilde{\mu}&=3\mu + 3\sigma^2  \\
\tilde{\sigma}&=3\sigma 
\end{align}
Now suppose $Y$ is a new stock with drift $\tilde{\mu}$ and volatility $\tilde{\sigma}$ and just substitute in the Black-Scholes formula for an european option with underlying $Y$ and strike $K$.

Comment: Hi sorry, I edited the quesiton now.@ab94